# Apereo CAS attribute caching

Tags: oauth-2.0, single-sign-on, cas

By default CAS queries attributes only when logging in and caches them for the whole SSO session.
I am using the OAuth 2.0 endpoint (/oauth2.0/profile) to get the attributes for the current user.
The attributes are stored in a database and retrieved using JDBC (the CAS is configured with cas.authn.attributeRepository.jdbc[0].x.y.z like properties).

Is it possible to turn caching off? I would like to query them every time when someone accesses the /oauth2.0/profile endpoint.

---

CAS Version 5.2.0

Answer (score 1):

Reference: 
https://apereo.github.io/cas/5.2.x/integration/Attribute-Release-Caching.html

By default, resolved attributes are cached to the length of the SSO session. If there are any attribute value changes since the commencement of SSO session, the changes are not reflected and returned back to the service upon release time.

The relationship between a CAS Principal and the underlying attribute repository source, that describes how and at what length the CAS Principal attributes should be cached is controlled by attribute repositories. Upon attribute release time, this component is consulted to ensure that appropriate attribute values are released to the scoped service, per the cache expiration policy. If the expiration policy has passed, the underlying attribute repository source will be consulted to figure out the available set of attributes.

This component also has the ability to resolve conflicts between existing principal attributes and those that are retrieved from repository source via a mergingStrategy property. This is useful if you want to preserve the collection of attributes that are already available to the principal that were retrieved from a different place during the authentication event, etc.

Furthermore, global caching policies can be controlled via:

```
# cas.authn.attributeRepository.expireInMinutes=30
# cas.authn.attributeRepository.maximumCacheSize=10000
# cas.authn.attributeRepository.merger=REPLACE|ADD|MERGE
```

Reference:
https://apereo.github.io/cas/5.2.x/installation/Configuration-Properties.html#authentication-attributes

The above notes describe the general caching strategies for attributes. Not sure if they have the same effect on the OAuth profile, but these are a good start.

Comment: These properties do not work, I tried to set expireInMinutes to 1 and waited for over 10 minutes. Updates in the database were not reflected.

Comment: i have exact problem like you, and the suggestion not working for me too. do you have any other advice?